# IIS 7.5 - Change path of administration.config file

Tags: iis, config, filepath

I'm taking over IIS maintenance for someone who just left and for some reason they copied the config files to a different drive and pointed IIS to look at them instead of the default C:\WINDOWS\System32\inetsrv\config.

QUESTION: How do I change it back to the default path? I assume I'll have to copy the current config files to the default directory first to maintain the configuration...

Thank you!

Scott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Click on the server in IIS Manager.
2. Scroll down to the "Management" section.
3. Double-click "Shared Configuration"
4. Turn this off to resort to local configuration settings.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone reaching this page due to an error locating the shared config file which completely blocks access to the IIS settings, you can run the below in PowerShell:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("C:\windows\system32\inetsrv\Microsoft.Web.Administration.dll") | Out-Null

$serverManager = New-Object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager
$config = $serverManager.GetRedirectionConfiguration()
$redirectionSection = $config.GetSection(“configurationRedirection”)
$redirectionSection.Attributes["enabled"].Value = “false”
$serverManager.CommitChanges()
```

This basically just turns off Shared Configuration so you can then access the IIS server manager.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do in "IIS" is:

1. Go to Management.
2. Shared configuration.
3. Right click
4. Open feature
5. Change physical path to any folder you want.
6. Move files to the specific folder.

Comment: I guess I need a reputation of at least 15 before I can vote up.